# Adjusting number of nodes in simulate graphs in ERGM

Tags: r, graph, statnet

I'm new to Statnet. I'm using ERGM (Exponential Random Graph Model) package to estimate parameters of a large network. Now I wan't to generate networks having the same statistical characteristics but with smaller number of nodes. For the same number of nodes I can use simulate command, but can't find an option for adjusting the number of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the formula for your model and the coeficients of the terms, I think you can simulate by passing in a formula with a different size network?

```
g.sim <- simulate(network(16) ~ edges + mutual, coef=c(0, 0))
```

So in code above, chante '16' to your network size, and enter the values for coefs.

However, I believe that many terms are not 'size invariant' meaning that the values of the coefficients may need to change with the network size, so it may not be a good thing to scale your network up or down to much. Or you would need to include 'offset' terms to control for this? This paper seems to have details: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3117581/